# Ajax on PhoneGap will not return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, cordova

This feels like a quite noob question, but what the heck. I'm sitting with a PhoneGap project and having some problems.
I followed a tutorial for a small twitterfeed with ajax (http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample) and it works like a charm. But, i am coding an smal API for logging in, logging out etc and etc and i almost got it to work.

I'll explain my problem:
i set up for example a BOOL variable, "b" that determines if the user is logged in or not.

var b = Do_Ajax('isloggedin');

and the function looks almost exactly like this:

```
    function Do_Ajax(what)
    {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if(what == "isloggedin")
        {
            ajax.open("GET", root() + "/?isloggedin",true);
            ajax.send();
        }

        //Get the results back           
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0))
            {
                eval('var data = ' + ajax.responseText + ';');
                var theResults = data.results;                    
                if(data['BOOL'] != null )
                {
                    return data['BOOL']; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If i now try an alert on this variable (b), i get "undefined". If i change "return" to an "alert" (where i print "return data['BOOL'];" - the php returns a json string) i will get the true or false value. If i then have an alert on the b variable AND in the function - the b variable alerts first and then the data['BOOL'] alerts.

So the problem is that the function returns undefined before it gets the data. How can i make the function "wait" to return this value until it has run that onreadystatechange stuff?

EDIT: One way to solve it is to declare a variable outside the function, like "var IsUserOnline = false;" and then in the function when the request it done set "IsUserOnline = data['BOOL']:" and later in the code just use this variable. But nah, i think the return-thinking would be best. I think my code will be very messy in the future when i will get/post more stuff via this function. Maybe it's just my thinking thats really wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function in the onreadystatechange function.

In your code (see my added comment):

```
function Do_Ajax(what)
    {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Get the results back           
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0))
        {
            eval('var data = ' + ajax.responseText + ';');
            var theResults = data.results;                    
            if(data['BOOL'] != null )
            {
                return data['BOOL']; 
            }

            //CALL YOUR FUNCTION HERE, 
            //OR THE CODE WHAT NEEDS TO HAPPEN AFTER A VALUE HAS BEEN RECEIVED 
            //BY THE AJAX REQUEST
        }
    }

    if(what == "isloggedin")
    {
        ajax.open("GET", root() + "/?isloggedin",true);
        ajax.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for repyl. But what function should i call? Call itself? What i would like to happen after the request is that the Do_Ajax should return the data['BOOL'] value. Right now it just returns undefined since it returns a value before the onreadystatechange stuff runs.

Comment: I think you should call a different function. You initialise the ajax request and in the onreadystate you put the code you want to run when you have the ajax result. - You could also try to put the 'if(logged_in)'-part after the onreadystatechange.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correct you are trying to call synchronous ajax call but the given function is still using asynchronous way so you will not receive the correct data. Try jQuery AJAX promise function which helps you call ajax request is synchronous pattern.

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

http://intridea.com/posts/fun-with-jquery-deferred

If you are not using jQuery then you might need to add a `callback` parameter after `what` and call the callback on response processing.

Comment: Hey and thanks for reply. Can you show me an example of the callback?